# Trying to statically link Boost

Tags: linux, boost, linker, static-linking

I am working in Linux, Eclipse CDT, g++, with Boost library. Having existing program which uses Boost thread, I try to link it statically instead of dynamically. /usr/local/lib directory contains the following files:

```
libbost_thread.a
libbost_thread.so
libbost_thread.1.41.0
```

Dynamic linking works:

```
g++  -o"MyProgram"  ./main.o   -lboost_thread
```

Static linking:

```
g++ -static -o"MyProgram"  ./main.o   -lboost_thread
```

produces huge number of messages like:

> undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_init'

How can I link statically to the Boost library?

Comment: This is almost identical to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328439/boost-static-linking and duplicate posts are generally frowned-upon.

Comment: @Dirk - they are related but definitely different.  The previous question was how to tell the linker to use the .a instead of the .so.  This question is about problems that happens once he does that.  It's better to post a new related question then to tack on new questions to an existing one.

Comment: @Samuel: I stand corrected, and learned from you about the `-pthread` linker option. Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For pthread_mutex_init, you want to compile/link with -pthread option:

```
g++ -static -pthread -o"MyProgram"  ./main.o   -lboost_thread
```

The problem is that functions like pthread_mutex_init are in a separate library.  Dynamic libraries can include the metadata for the fact that it needs the separate library (so libboost_thread.so includes the fact that it needs libpthread).

But static libraries don't have that information.  So you need to provide the reference to any necessary libraries when you link statically.

As for using `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`, it's slightly preferable because it not only links the necessary library, but provides any other options that should be used (such a `-D_REENTRANT` to the compiler).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the important distinction between `-lpthread` and `-pthread`

Comment: -static -pthread 
Thank you, finally it succeeded! What is -pthread? Something boost-specific or linker option? It looks like a magic for me, but I need to understand this.
I also work with Boost Program Options (-lboost_program_options), what switch should I use to link it statically?

Comment: @AlexFarber: -pthread is a gcc option.  It tells the compiler to properly build your code for threading.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `-lpthread` to your invocation.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux a dynamic library may automatically depend on other dynamic libraries so that when you link it, you get the other libraries for free. When linking statically, there is no such system and you have to specify the other libraries manually.