# Static linking, boost::locale

Tags: c++, boost, static-linking

Due to various non-compatible with each other boost library versions on different systems. I need to link statically program that uses boost::locale.

But I fail to it because of the boost::locale::generator.

```
// simple example - static_locate.cpp 
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

int main () {
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    return 0;
}
```

g++ build:

```
$ g++          staic_locale.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_locale || works
$ g++ --static staic_locale.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_locale && a lot of linking errors
```

Refering to [Trying to statically link Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348200/trying-to-statically-link-boost). Adding `-pthread` and/or `-lboost_thread` a little bit helps, but still not completely.

[build log (nopaste)](http://nopaste.linux-dev.org/?1120099)

system:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="15.10 (Wily Werewolf)"
```

boost version:

```
$ apt-cache policy libboost-dev 
libboost-dev:
  Installed: 1.58.0.0ubuntu1
```

Comment: Posting some of those errors could help, or a [nopaste](http://nopaste.linux-dev.org/) if you need to paste a lot of text (it's still better for completeness to post the relevant errors here though)

Comment: Might also need `boost_chrono` and/or `boost_thread`. Maybe also ICU or iconv (whichever one it uses on Linux). It should be pretty clear from the error messages, once you actually show them.

Comment: I have made little progress by linking also `-licuuc`, but still it is not a solution. @MarcoA @DanMašek  -- (http://nopaste.linux-dev.org/?1120102)