# Error while loading shared libraries

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I'm trying to fix this issue but i cant.

I have a problem with libboost.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libboost_filesystem.so.1.42.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also did reinstall of it.

> apt-get remove libboost1.42-dev apt-get install libboost1.42-dev

But it still doesn't work.

I also read it: [Compiled C++ program raises "cannot open shared object file" on another system though the file is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078292/compiled-c-program-raises-cannot-open-shared-object-file-on-another-system-t)

But still idk what i should do.

Can you explain me step by step how i can fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the `file` command on both your binary and the boost library, and compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my memory still serves me well, Ubuntu's `libboost-dev` package does not install the entire set of Boost libraries and only some limited set of it. So you need to install `libboost-filesystem-dev`. The easiest way for you though would probably be to install `libboost-all-dev` that should bring the entire collection of Boost libraries to your system.

Comment: OKAY, It's working !

I just used apt-get install libboost-all-dev and i recompiled my program (wrote in c++), and all works !

Thank's again but i cant give any rpeoutation points (i have 6 of 15).

Comment: @user2117529: I am glad to be of help! Don't worry about the rep. Not to mention that accepting an answer gives it +15 :-)