# Cppumaker - libreg.so.3: cannot open shared object file

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

Using Ubuntu 64bit, openoffice (and SDK) version 4.1.1

Trying to use cppumaker (called from a makefile) to generate some files:

> /opt/openoffice4/sdk/bin/cppumaker -Gc -BUCR -T"org.openoffice.sheet.addin.XRNG" -O. /opt/openoffice4/program/types.rdb > /opt/openoffice4/program/oovbaapi.rdb RNG.rdb

Error message:

> /opt/openoffice4/sdk/bin/cppumaker: error while loading shared libraries: libreg.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   make: *** [com] Error 127

Found help here -> [Compiled C++ program raises "cannot open shared object file" on another system though the file is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078292/compiled-c-program-raises-cannot-open-shared-object-file-on-another-system-t?rq=1)

Ran: ldconfig -p | grep libreg.so.3 (not there)
Added a file to the /etc/ld.so.conf.d directory, with the path to libreg.so.3

Ran "sudo ldconfig" "to update your system's ld cache."

Thanks!