# Boost static linking in unix

Tags: boost, static-linking

I am using the Boost library in Unix, GCC. I read the following topic: [Boost static linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328439/boost-static-linking) and added -static to my Makefile. However, this does not work.

Here is my Makefile:

```
all: nbbo

nbbo: nbbo.o reader.o
    g++ -static -O3 -ffast-math -funroll-loops -ansi -pedantic-errors -L/usr/lib -lboost_filesystem -lboost_serialization -lboost_iostreams -lz -I /usr/include/boost -o nbbo nbbo.o reader.o

nbbo.o: nbbo.cpp
    g++ -static -O3 -ffast-math -funroll-loops -ansi -pedantic-errors -I /usr/include/boost -c -o nbbo.o nbbo.cpp

reader.o: reader.cc reader.h
    g++ -static -O3 -ffast-math -funroll-loops -ansi -pedantic-errors -I /usr/include/boost -c -o reader.o reader.cc

clean:
    rm *.o
```

And here is the error message:

```
nbbo.o: In function `__tcf_10':
nbbo.cpp:(.text+0x3d9): undefined reference to `boost::serialization::extended_type_info::key_unregister() const'
nbbo.cpp:(.text+0x3e3): undefined reference to `boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::type_unregister()'
nbbo.cpp:(.text+0x3fb): undefined reference to `boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::~extended_type_info_typeid_0()'
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Which "UNIX" are you using? Using the -static flag should work fine on linux. But not on OSX. On OSX you have to remove the static flag and give the complete path to the library in order to link statically. I dont know how this would work on other "UNIXes"

eg.

```
g++ ..... /path/to/your/lib.a ... -o ..
```